# Part Time(Germany) vs Full Time PhD(Netherland)

Tags: phd, professorship, supervision, part-time

I have a very complex situation. I am doing my PhD from last 14 months in the area of Computational Social Science in Germany. I have 2 publication(1 workshop and 1 Journal), 2 submitted paper(Tier 1 conference). My PhD was funded by a scholarship and the scholarship was not enough for survival. So, I decided to quit the scholarship and look for a job. I got a job in the public research institute in Germany with 100% TVL-13. The new work is in semantic technologies for biological data. In this case, there is no relation between my PhD supervisor and manager at a public research institute. My PhD supervisor agreed that he will not treat me as a part-time student but he will not pay anything(which is fine for me), here I can get a degree in 3 years. But I have two manage both works at a time.

I also got an offer from Netherland, where I have to restart my PhD. The area of work is semantic technologies for biological data. I will also get a good salary(lesser than Germany) in Netherland. Here, I have to invest in the next 4 years to get a degree.

In the long term, I wanted to become a professor. My preference is to get a good salary and finish my PhD quickly.

I wanted to live in Germany because I can get long term resident in 2 years and I am afraid to restart the PhD again because it requires a lot of work to understand the topic. I am also afraid that if I stay in Germany and unable to manage my PhD and job, then I will be in big trouble.

I am writing this post to have a genius opinion/suggestion regarding my conditions. I understand in the end, it depends on me but suggestions from experience person will be really helpful.

Comment: I think you get to the point at the end: It's all pretty much a question of personal preference that we can't really help you much with.

Comment: Depending on where you got the offer, you might be able to live in Germany and do your PhD in the Netherlands. This is not uncommon and there are many rules in place that take care of your tax situation and other things, not only in academia, but also in all kind of industries. This should also not prevent you from becoming long term resident, but better check before you sign.

Comment: @Mark Likely difficult if you are not an EU citizen.

Comment: Yes, the workplace is far from the German border. Will choosing Germany affect me in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really up to you. I would start with making a table listing all the advantages and disadvantages of each position. By the way you formulated that question, you already started that table

However, when making that table remember that the 3 and 4 years of funding do *not* correspond with how long it takes to finish a PhD; it only corresponds to how long you get paid. It is very common that people need more time to finish their PhD thesis. This is especially true when you try to do a PhD part-time. So I would predict that you will need to budget more time to finish in the German part-time position compared to the Dutch full-time position. This obviously depends on the specifics, e.g. if you have a very understanding boss and your PhD project is very close to your "normal" job, then the part-time PhD position could become very close to a full-time one. But that is something you have to find out.